# MVC Partial views rendering cached version

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, partial-views, page-refresh

For whatever reason, whenever I build my project, any changes I've made to a view that are not html do not get displayed.  Instead it pulls all the info from the partial view (which in our application doesn't get updated when I make a change in the view). So every time I build my project, the application serves me the partial view and I have to go into each view that I made changes in and make some sort of html change in order for the changes I made prior to the build display.  Eventually, this functionality will change, but right now my boss doesn't want to mess with it just yet.  I've tried disabling cache in chrome's dom (f12) as well as downloading an extension to force the page to not display any chached versions of pages but that doesn't seem to help.  What else can I do until we get the partial views removed properly?

***UPDATE:***

I kinda goofed on the title.  Whats happening is the generated files are what are being served to me from my localhost rather than any changes I made to a view (html or otherwise), if I made those changes prior to a build.

so in the view I'd have this:

```
<body>
<div>Hello World!</div
<div><h2>Sample Text</h2></div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
//Some Javascript code
});
```

Which is the way the page was originally created by someone else.  They also manually made a partial generated file and that file doesn't rre-generate when I make changes to the view.

So if I made these changes:

```
<body>
<div>Hello World again!</div
<div><h2>Sample Text</h2></div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
//Some Javascript code
});
```

and then built the project, it would not serve me these changes, it would grab the generated file (which didn't get updated with my changes) and serve that to me unless AFTER I do the build, I go into that specific view and make an HTML Change (for some reason making a change with Javascript doesn't help).  Then I can see my changes.  AND it will stay that way until I do another build at which point, everything reverts back to the partial generated views until I make an HTML change in the view.

Comment: Some example code demonstrating the problem would be nice.

Comment: Check my update, hopfelly this helps better explain.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the Generated files is the only way I can see to fix the problem I just wasn't sure if it would break the application and it doesn't.